# Repeated query parameter in spring-cloud-contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Is it possible to specify repeated query parameters through the groovy syntax in spring cloud contract 1.2.5.RELEASE?

I would like to create a contract that generates a get request to `/path?type=1&type=2`.

I tried the following in the contract test groovy file

```
 urlPath('/path') {
  queryParameters {
    parameter type: [1, 2]
  }
}
```

the generated `RestTest` contains the wrong type unfortunately:

```
.queryParam("type","[1, 2]")
```

instead of

```
.queryParam("type", 1, 2)
```